# A bit unsure how to hook my power supply up to my video card

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I'm putting together a new machine for the first time in quite a while, and I've hit a snag.

My new power supply is the [EVGA SuperNOVA 1000W P2 80 PLUS PLATINUM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817438013).

My new graphics card is the [EVGA GTX 780 Ti Classified K|NGP|N Edition](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814487037).

The power ports for the graphics card look like this:

[image]

The back of the power supply looks like this:

[image]

Pretty simple, right?  Hook 2 8-pin VGA connectors up to the 8-pin ports on the card?

However, the graphics card came with 3 cables:

[image]

[image]

The cable on the right plugs into the 6-pin port on the graphics card.  The other end of it has 2 3-pin power connectors.  The middle and left cables plug into the 8-pin ports of the graphics card.  The other ends of them have 2 6-pin connectors.

So now I'm confused about how to power this graphics card.  **I think you have to use the supplied cables** to supply enough power to the card, but I'm not sure how to connect them to the PSU.

Comment: Use the power supply cables.  The answer is also in the manual for the graphics card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PSU comes with 6x 6+2 Pin PCI-E connectors. No need to use the cables that came with your graphics card.

Comment: That is my hope.  However, I get the feeling that the card needs more power, which is why the cables were supplied.  Of course, my knowledge of electricity is very limited.

Comment: The cables that came with the GPU are adapters. Like, when you don't have the right cables on your PSU, you can use the cables that came with your GPU to connect the GPU with the PSU.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for your answer.  Could you tell me what is being plugged into the back of the card on this image? http://www.evga.com/articles/00813/images/univ/dedicated_GPU_power.jpg

Comment: Also, if I were to not use the supplied cable that is a 6-pin-to-3-pin cable, what would I plug into that port?

Comment: I really am not sure what that cable is, seems like a 5-pin PWN fan connector, but couldn't tell you the use of it. Can't find anything on the web about it either. The 4-pin to 6-pin molex adapter shouldn't be used. My guess is that it's for the 6-pin connection on the right side of the card (which I think is optional). You could ofcourse plug a 6-pin connector in it, but I would not use the molex adapter. Just get one of the 6-pin connectors of your PSU and plug it in there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Which one of the 6-pin connectors on the PSU should I use?  Four of them are labeled "SATA" and 2 of them are labeled "RERP."  Or does it not matter?

Comment: I don't think it really matters, I'd go with RERP1

Comment: My pleasure, let me know when you've got your new build up and running :)

Comment: It won't be until Christmas.  I cut some cost corners by throwing the PSU (I don't actually have it yet) and SSD out as gift ideas :)   I don't suppose having thermal paste sit on an unpowered CPU for 3 weeks will be a problem, right?  I mean, anyone could just as easily leave their computer off for 3 weeks.

Comment: You mean leaving thermal paste on the CPU without having a CPU cooler on it? If that's the case, than no. You'll need to remove the thermal paste and re-apply it when you install the cooler. If there's already a cooler on it, I don't think it should be a problem. To my knowledge the thermal paste spreads out evenly by applying pressure (that is, if the right ammount is applied), so there's no warmth needed for the paste to spread evenly, which means it doesn't have to be powered up. Can't think of anything else that could go wrong.

Comment: I have the heatsink (CPU cooler) installed.  I just didn't know how dry the thermal paste gets over time if there is no heat (ie: the computer isn't powered on).  Thanks for your response again!

Comment: Well, I have it all built, but I'm not getting any display on my  monitor! [http://superuser.com/questions/856863/new-pc-build-monitor-wont-display-anything](http://superuser.com/questions/856863/new-pc-build-monitor-wont-display-anything)

Comment: Scratch that!  All is well!